# How to create a widget of a drawer

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter,
I wanted to created a widget of a drawer but from some reason the drawer seems to not being able to accept the `child:` key word.

The code below is from Flutter's official website, however when using it I got an error: `The named parameter 'child' isn't defined.`

How can I solve this issue?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Drawer extends StatelessWidget {
  const Drawer({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      //Child seems not to be recognized here.
      child: ListView( 
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            child: Text('Drawer Header'),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Item 1'),
            onTap: () {
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Item 2'),
            onTap: () {
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's occurred because you're trying to use class in itself, you should rename your `StatelessWidget` – `class MyDrawerWidget extends StatelessWidget`